# Cannot install Tensorflow on PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I am trying to install TensorFlow on PyCharm in `Project > Python Interpreter` to meet the requirement of the TF Developer Certificate exam.

My computer is Windows 10. On the `Python Console`, I print the python version:

```
>>> print(sys.version)
3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Then I go to `File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter > Available Packages`, find and install the Tensorflow package. I install the default version which is `2.2.0`. My `pip` version is `20.1.1`.

But I cannot install it, it displays this error:

```
Error occurred:
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)

Command output:
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I have searched for this solution but I cannot find anything that helps me solve it. Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

**Update:**
When I install the TF in my cmd, it installs successfully.

```
C:\Users\User>pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.2.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires: six, google-pasta, wrapt, astunparse, gast, wheel, scipy, absl-py, numpy, tensorboard, termcolor, grpcio, h5py, keras-preprocessing, tensorflow-estimator, protobuf, opt-einsum
Required-by:
```

**Update 2:**

I follow this set up instruction by TF: [Link](https://www.tensorflow.org/site-assets/downloads/marketing/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf)

**Update 3:**

So I tried to install via package location but it doesn't work (Python 3.7 CPU-only):

```
pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

Error:

```
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.2.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

**Update 4:**

I create a new project, then use `conda` environment to install TF. Then it works.

But I still don't understand why using normal `venv`, it cannot install.

[image]

**Update 5:**

Everything works fine on Ubuntu when following the [instruction](https://www.tensorflow.org/site-assets/downloads/marketing/cert/Setting_Up_TF_Developer_Certificate_Exam.pdf) by TF.

Comment: Looks like version is not passed to pip during installation for some reason.  Have your tried installing TensorFlow manually using pip?

Comment: @PavelBotsman I just installed it using cmd without creating a virtual environment, it installs successfully. You can check my update.

Comment: I suggest using `Python3.6` to install `Tensorflow`.

Comment: @Saeed I can't use Python 3.6 because the TF Developer Certificate exam requires Python 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was trying to use TensorFlow on Windows 10 while having multiple versions of Python installed.
What I did was uninstall all versions except the most updated one. If I needed an older version I would use [Conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) virtual environment.

Comment: Yes, that right. I have to use `conda` to install it. It just does not work with `venv`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Thanks for your insight/experience. While it may prove to be helpful, understand that this reads a little bit more like a Comment than an Answer according to SO guidelines, so it might be removed (as an Answer) by the platform. Feel free to edit if you think you can turn it into a more complete, self contained, exacting, higher quality Answer. Once you have enough reputation you can Comment on any post. StackOverflow.com/help has more info on guidelines for the format of this site. We appreciate your contribution & look forward to more.

Comment: @SherylHohman Thanks for the clarification. I appreciate your effort.